# S3 GetBucketACL() throws exception For Singapore Bucket - The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am creating AWS bucket of 'Singapore' region. After creating I am getting acl of BUCKET, that time it throw **exception - "(S3Exception) software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint. (Service: S3, Status Code: 301)"**

My code is -

**Main Method**

```
{
     s3Client = awsJdkClient.createCredentialsWithAWSJdk(sLocationConstaints);
     sBucket = awsJdkClient.createAWSBucket(s3Client, sTempBucketName);
     AmazonS3Requests.increase_PUT_BUCKET_Requeset();
     if (getDetails(sBucket) == true) {
            objBucketOperationEvent.addMessageToSatusbar("Bucket " + sBucket + " has been created successfully.", true);
     } else {
            objBucketOperationEvent.addMessageToSatusbar("Bucket " + sBucket + " has not been created.", true);
            return false;
     }
 }
   
         public GetBucketAclResponse getBucketACL( String bucketName) {
                try {
                    GetBucketAclRequest getBucketAclRequest = GetBucketAclRequest.builder().bucket(bucketName).build();
                    GetBucketAclResponse bucketAclS3Client = this.s3Client.getBucketAcl(getBucketAclRequest);          //Here it throw exception
                    return bucketAclS3Client;
                } catch (S3Exception e) {
                   throw e;
                }
            }
        
        private boolean getDetails(String bucketname) {
                try {
                    objBucketExplorer.writeDebug("CreateBucket: getDetails() is invoked");
                    if (awsJdkClient == null) {
                        objBucketExplorer.writeDebug("CreateBucket-while getting detail: return unsuccessfully  from getDetails() due to objService found null");
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (awsJdkClient.getBucketACL(bucketname) == null) {
                        AmazonS3Requests.increase_GET_BUCKET_Requeset();
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        AmazonS3Requests.increase_GET_BUCKET_Requeset();
                        return true;
                    }
                } catch (S3Exception ex) {
                    String stackNum = Utility.exceptionHandler(ex);
                    objBucketExplorer.writeDebug("CreateBucket: return unsuccessfully from getDetails() :Error " + ex.getMessage() + " Stacktrace " + stackNum);
                    return false;
                }
        
            }
public S3Client createCredentialsWithAWSJdk(String regionString) {
        try {

            AwsBasicCredentials awsCreds = AwsBasicCredentials.create(
                    ACCESS_KEY,
                    SECRET_KEY);
            S3ClientBuilder s3ClientBuilder = S3Client.builder().credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(awsCreds));
            if (regionString != null &&  !regionString.isEmpty()) {
                Region region = Region.of(regionString);
                s3ClientBuilder.region(region);
            }
            S3Client s3Client = s3ClientBuilder.build();
            return s3Client;
        } catch (S3Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public String createAWSBucket(S3Client s3Client, String bucketName) {
        try {
            S3Waiter s3Waiter = s3Client.waiter();
            CreateBucketRequest bucketRequest = CreateBucketRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .build();

            CreateBucketResponse few = s3Client.createBucket(bucketRequest);
            HeadBucketRequest bucketRequestWait = HeadBucketRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .build();
            return bucketRequestWait.bucket();
        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            if(e.awsErrorDetails().errorCode().equalsIgnoreCase("BucketAlreadyOwnedByYou")){
                return bucketName;
            }
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you properly initializing the client in correct region? Something like AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                       .withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2)
                       .build();

Comment: Region for Singapore is "ap-southeast-1" refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html

Comment: WHat API are you using? Is awsJdkClient a custom class? 

s3Client = awsJdkClient.createCredentialsWithAWSJdk(sLocationConstaints);

Comment: @smac2020    we use aws sdk v4 API. And  for above method post is updated.